# Starting point for minimal Visual C++ X-Y Graph

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, graph

Is there a simple example of a program in Visual C++ that graphs x-y data?

This is to operate a small spectrometer.  I would like a starting point that shows a graph and does little else, to which I will add controls, a thread that reads the data sent asynchronously from the instrument over a COM port and some plumbing to update the graph.

Thank you

Comment: Two votes to close.  Well, I guess I should have expected this kind of behavior from stackoverflow.   It is a really unpleasant place to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'simple' plotting application is actually not all that simple.  Also, if you make it as simple as possible, then adding bells and whistles is impossible without a re-write, so it becomes a dead end.

Anyway, this is what I use for developing windows applications that need to display a plot :

```
Sample plot application:

#include "wex.h"          //  https://github.com/JamesBremner/windex
#include "plot2d.h"

int main()
{
        wex::gui& fm = wex::maker::make();
        fm.move( {50,50,1200,600} );

        // construct plot to be drawn on form
        wex::plot::plot& thePlot = wex::maker::make<wex::plot::plot>(fm);
        thePlot.move( {30,30,1200,600});
        //thePlot.Grid( true );

        // resize plot when form resizes
        fm.events().resize([&](int w, int h )
        {
            thePlot.move( {30,30,w,h} );
            thePlot.update();
        });

        // construct plot traces
        wex::plot::trace& t1 = thePlot.AddStaticTrace();
        wex::plot::trace& t2 = thePlot.AddStaticTrace();

        // provide some data for first trace
        std::vector< double > d1 { 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10 };
        t1.set( d1 );

        // plot in blue
        t1.color( 0x0000FF );

        // provide data for second trace
        std::vector< double > d2 { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20 };
        t2.set( d2 );

        // plot in red
        t2.color( 0xFF0000 );

        // show and run
        fm.show();
        fm.run();
}
```

By the way, there is no need to gather the data using a separate thread ( always a fruitful source of bugs ).  Instead, use the windows API message pump, like this:

```
    wex::button &btnTime = wex::maker::make<wex::button>(fm);
    btnTime.move(300, 10, 100, 20);
    btnTime.text("Real Time");
    btnTime.tooltip("Display moving line plot that updates in real time");
    btnTime.events().click([&]
                           {
        // construct plot trace
        // displaying 100 points before they scroll off the plot
        plot::trace& t1 = thePlot.AddRealTimeTrace( 100 );

        // plot in blue
        t1.color( 0xFF0000 );

        // create timer handler to provide new data regularly
        fm.events().timer([&](int id)
        {
            static int p = 0;
            t1.add( 10 * sin( p++ / 10.0 ) );
            thePlot.update();
        });
```

Comment: Neat, thank you.  It looks like he provides a nice set of examples.  Will give it a try.   How do you compile it?   Do you use visual studio?  If so, how do you create the project?   Or do you have a command line to compile it?

Comment: I use VSCODE.  A demo VSCODE project is available in the repo.  You can also use the provided makefile directly from the command line.  Note that it is a header only library, so there is no need to compile it separately.

Comment: The reason for the thread is that the data comes asynchronously over a com port in bursts of 8KB per frame at 480Mb/s.  it needs a listener.

Comment: 480Mb/s is fast.  Or do you mean that is the speed at which each frame arrives and there is a long, variable gap between each frame?

Comment: Note that the default buffer size on the USB serial port ( I assume you are using this rather than a legacy COM port ) is 4K.  You can increase the size of this to hold several frames.  ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0 ) Then you can poll the driver using the windows API message pump without needing a separate thread.  Have you looked at https://jamesbremner.github.io/windex/classwex_1_1com.html

Comment: I am looking at it now.   Can the pump poll the com port at 100/sec?

Comment: In the demo, there are lines like this   form.events().resize([&](....etc.   Presumably that is defining an event handler for resize.   Where do I find what handlers it will recognize?    Presumably for a live graph I have to supply a redraw or repaint of some sort, and trigger it from something?  How?

Comment: Re COM, it looks great.   It still needs a thread to poll it.  Also, need ascii with stop at \n, and, binary with stop at byte count.  Here is how the data is sent (println() appends a \n),   https://github.com/drmcnelson/Linear-CCD-with-LTSpice-KiCAD-Firmware-and-Python-Library/blob/158dbd7092335d02c7ce6e7730f7302ca574d460/TCD1304Rev2b_Firmware.231218/TCD1304Rev2b_Firmware.231218.ino#L646

Comment: On windows you can get a  reliable polling frequency up to 200/sec  Any faster and things start to fall apart.

Comment: " Where do I find what handlers it will recognize?"  https://jamesbremner.github.io/windex/classwex_1_1eventhandler.html

Comment: Thank you, I found the event handlers.   What do you think of using asyncReadComplete() to launch read_async?    Maybe one byte at a time untll end of line?   There is a message that signals binary data to follow, so I can just do  a read at that point, if the delay is only 1 msec-ish?  (An async read until end of line would be super useful, python has it - nudge nudge :)

Comment: I have not found the winapi message pump, is there a better keyword to look for it?   The resize readbuffer seems to be C# only.  Is there a way to do this from within windex?  Thank you.

Comment: BTW. I am over the hump, I have an app that compiles and shows a graph in the main window.  Fantastic.  Thank you.   Windex is really a super useful contribution.  I wonder how to make it more well known.

Comment: "Windex is really a super useful contribution"  Really?  So why is there no upvote on my answer?

Comment: "I have not found the winapi message pump"  There is no need to look for it.  Simply create a timer and poll the com port when it fires.  Windows will look after everything for you.  https://jamesbremner.github.io/windex/classwex_1_1timer.html

Comment: Take a look at how the demo does it https://github.com/JamesBremner/windex/blob/f08bd704b3f11e7c38e250202d24a34272511e6e/demo/demo.cpp#L670-L680`

Comment: Polling is rarely a good idea for an inherently async system, more so with fast bursts.   (Also, there are different time requirements, the data flow has to be reliable for 50 packets at 100packets/sec, the display can lag). OTOH, windows' async response time is notoriously so poor.... See this superuser.com/questions/1199613/…. But, I am going to try the async anyway, maybe with a large enough buffer and a check-more-available in the callback, it can be made to work.  Can we set the readbuffer size from windex? Do we have the comport object easily available?